# Symfony 2.5: Authentication fails at every second page call

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have updated a symfony 2.0 project to 2.5 and now i am faced with some problems with authentication:

After submitting the username and password i am authenticated. If i follow a link in the secured area or if i am refreshing the current page i get this error:

```
There is no user provider for user "XXX\AccountBundle\Entity\Worker".
```

After refreshing again i am authenticated.
After the next refresh i am not.
After refreshing again i am authenticated.
And so on …

This is my security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    XXX\AccountBundle\Entity\Worker:
        algorithm:   sha1
        iterations: 1
        encode_as_base64: false

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ACCOUNT_OWNER:       [ROLE_USER]

providers:
    users:
        entity: { class: XXXAccountBundle:Worker, property: email }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    application:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous:  ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /dashboard
            use_referer:        true
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path:     /
            domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

If i remove the "remember me"-section i get logged out after the first request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the authentication problem appeared every second call i had good reasons to check the serializable stuff of the user object. Everything was fine there, but i had to reimplement some custom functions in the UserRepository class where the user is loaded.

Because of the error message i searched for several hours at the wrong place. My security.yml setup was fine.

Now the authentication process works again :)